# Authentication - browser autologin to domain, using Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, dns, ldap, passport.js

I'm no security Guru, and I am trying to implement a specific security requirement for my application that I haven't been able to figure out.

I would like to connect my node (express) application to an LDAP server (AD) and authenticate against it, but in addition to this I would like to have my browser automatically submit domain credentials if the user is logged in to a domain.

I have seen a working example of this in Apache Tomcat using Waffle, but I am trying to get this working on Node.js.

#### WHERE I AM AT

- I know you can tell a browser to 'permit' sending credentials, for
  example in Firefox you set the following about:config values:

> ```
> network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
> network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris
> network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris”
> ```

- I am using `PassportJS` for my authentication, and using the NPM module `Passport-windowsauth` as my authentication strategy, I can successfully talk to my Active Directory and authenticate a user manually from my server code.

#### WHERE I AM LOST

Though I did set the config values as above in Firefox, I have no idea how to tell the browser to send these credentials on navigating to `/login', or in what form these credentials come, or how to parse them. I don't know where to start.

I asked the guy who did this in Tomcat & Waffle and he actually didn't know how this part worked - it was all under the hood and so was 'magical'.

Where do I start on this?

Comment: Are you seeing the 401 get sent back from your server with the correct authentication headers?

Comment: I just get an unauthorized message back, and my firebug won't let me look at the request for whatever reason.